# ERROR: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is correctly initialized before accessing data

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a very **simple database** android app. It takes an input and display result. Add button is used to add the input and delete button for deleting the input stored in SQLite database. My **cursor** in Android SQLite is pointed correctly but still I am facing the error: **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.** Following is the cursor part:
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

```
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Traversing through DB
    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("studentname")) !=null)
        {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("studentname"));
            dbString +="\n"; }

        c.moveToNext(); }
        db.close();

        return dbString;
```

I have tried changing cursor positions but still same error appearing. I have researched on other sites and same is the concept but still there is an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, there is no `studentname` column in your result set, if `c.getColumnIndex("studentname")` is returning `-1`.

Comment: You are 100% right. My bad, it is StudentName, not studentname. Thanks a lot CommonsWare, you solved my mistake for which I was struggling for about 2 hours. I'll be very careful next time with my naming conventions. App working perfectly fine now. Thanks again and take care :)

Comment: this is right that I am having this problem, because I wanted to add a new column in an existing table. any idea how to add  ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above by CommonsWare, this apparently look like that there is no column of such name and its absolutely true. My column name is StudentName, not studentname, hence there was a mistake with respect to the proper column name, which resulted in to -1 (No column at all to work on). Thanks CommonsWare for pointing out my silly mistake :)

> For those who want to start SQLite understanding with android, can check this course which I am also a part of and learning from it currently : https://www.udemy.com/androidcourse/ available at [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com)