# Sqlite DB Cursor issue

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am having this exception every time "Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it." i tried everything but nothing worked.
My code below:

```
val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_POS_ORDERS
val db = this.readableDatabase

var cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null)
cursor.moveToFirst()
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.ID))
               orderId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.ORDER_ID))
               dateandtime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.DATE_AND_TIME))
               restaurant_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.RESTAURANT_ID))
               restaurant_name =
                   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.RESTAURANT_NAME))
               deliveryType_decription =
                   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.DELIVERY_TYPE_DESCRIPTION))
               paymentType_decription =
                   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.PAYMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION))
               totalAmount = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.TOTAL_AMOUNT))
               process_order = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PosOrderKeys.PROCESS_ORDER))
        
               val posOrder = PosOrderData(id,orderId,dateandtime,restaurant_id,restaurant_name)
               posOrderList.add(posOrder)

           } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            cursor.close()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819266/6843158) help ?

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue i have a large table and i missed to add to column while creating table but added that column in Select query.